# Is there a way to override the same name `npmScopes` inside `.yarnrc.yml`?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-registry, yarn-v3

#### Background

My organization has two registries of the same name (say `my-org`); one is public and is hosted via [NPM](https://registry.npmjs.org), and the other one is private and hosted in [GitHub](https://npm.pkg.github.com). Unfortunately, there is no registry mirroring between the two, and internal packages that require an `npmAuthToken` are published to the private one, while the others to public.

#### Current Status

We are currently in a process of migrating to Yarn v3 and initialized our `.yarnrc.yml` like:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules

npmScopes:
  "my-org":
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: ${MY_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN-fallback}
    npmRegistryServer: https://npm.pkg.github.com # URL for private registry
```

... and for the sake of simplicity our `package.json` contain these two dependencies that needs to be installed:

- `@my-org/public-pkg` *(hosted in NPM publicly)*
- `@my-org/private-pkg` *(hosted in GitHub privately)*

#### Problem

Since the `yarnrc.yml` is configured to look in the private registry for everything with `@my-org/*` pattern, it fails to retrieve the `@my-org/public-pkg` package, **when ideally it should look for it in the public registry as a fallback first before eventually failing.**

##### Question

- Does anybody know if there's a way to override scope names inside `.yarnrc.yml` or if there's a workaround for this? Just curious.
- Or is the only solution is to mirror these repositories from public towards private?

Comment: I have also started this discussion on GitHub here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/discussions/5663